# Last four digits of $S=9+9^2+9^3+\ldots+9^{400}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

What are the last four digits of the following sum:

$$S=9+9^2+9^3+\ldots+9^{400} ?$$

Comment: No attempt at the answer??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** This is a geometric sum, you can sum it and then do mod $10000$ to get the last $4$ digits

Comment: mod 10000? [spacefiller]

Comment: @akkkk - thanks, updated

Answer (score 3):

**HINT 2:** Use Euler's Theorem: if $a$ and $m$ are coprime, we have $a^n\equiv a^{n \text{ mod }\varphi(m)} \text{ mod }m$, where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function. What is $\varphi(10000)$?